# TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String with gsub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to iterate through all users in my system and update the username using the email address minus the @ and everything after the @.
If the email is nil or an empty string, then I just assign unknown_user with the current iteration index:

```
User.all.each do |user|
  puts user.email
  username = (user.email.present?? user.email.gsub(/(.+)@.+/,$1) : "unknown_user#{i}")
  puts username
end
```

It fails with:

```
crodriguez
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
    from (irb):45:in `gsub'
    from (irb):45:in `block in irb_binding'
```

I do not know where the nil value is. If email is not present, then gsub is never invoked. What am I missing here?

Comment: please note this is not actually updating anything it is simply assigning a local variable. My apologies if you already are aware. Also it does not appear you are validating the email address as "crodriguez" is not a valid email

Comment: FYI: To use a backreference in the gsub replacement pattern, just use `'\1'`: `gsub(/(.+)@.+/, '\1')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nil value isn't your `user.email`. The `gsub` method expects a string as its second argument, which it will replace matches with. As mu has pointed out separately, the `$1` global variable isn't yet available when the arguments are being passed to `gsub`.

Assuming you're wanting only the name portion of an email, you don't even need a regex:

```
username, _ = user.email&.split('@')
```

In this, `username` will be `nil` when `user.email` is `nil`, and the string before `@` otherwise.

If you do want to set `username` to a default string, as in your example:

```
User.find_each do |user|
  username = user.email.split('@').first if user.email.present?
  username ||= "unknown_user_#{user.id}"
  # do something with `username`
end
```

I've done away with the ternary here because it's not as amenable to reading or understanding the code, and it's less easy to change in the future. You could refactor to use it, if desired.

Comment: A more compact option: `username = user.email.to_s.split('@').first || "unknown_user_#{user.id}"`

Comment: @Thilo You'll get a NoMethodError here when `user.email` is nil. ;)

Comment: @coreyward `nil.to_s #=> ""` :). Now the real problem is it does not appear that he is validating the email address and it may not contain an @ at all.

Comment: @engineersmnky Ah, didn't catch that, or how it then relies on `.first` being nil. That's clever, but dangerous. Someone's going to come along and mess that up down the road.

Comment: Still, if I were going for brevity (over readability): `user.email&.split('@')[0] || "unknown_user"`.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @coreyward validation isn't really in scope here and not done in the original question either. My version is just for brevity, not necessarily better.

Comment: Readers, if you are puzzled by the `&` in `user.email &.split('@')`, it is the recently-introduced [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). Corey, you need to escape your emoticon's right (from emotion's perspective) arm.

Answer (score 5):

The numbered global variables (`$1`, `$2`, ...) are only available when you use the block form of `String#gsub` so you could say:

```
user.email.gsub(/(.+)@.+/) { $1 }
```

When you say:

```
user.email.gsub(/(.+)@.+/, $1)
```

the `$1` global is evaluated when the `gsub` argument list is being built (i.e. before `gsub` can assign it a value) so you shouldn't expect `$1` to have any useful value.

That said, I'd probably go with [coreyward's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41401039/479863) and not bother with a regex at all.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize the behind the curtain on the global assignment. You're always one step ahead of me.

Comment: @coreyward The numbered globals are a wart copied from Perl, they smell musty and are sort of a misfeature IMO.